# I dont understand why my django signals isnt creating object into database

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

Im trying to build a notification app where a user follows another user, they get notified in a notification page, my problem now is that i don't understand why the signals isnt creating an object into the notification model database. Please help. Heres the code

Models:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="notifications_assigned_to_user")
    group = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=notification_types, default='N')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    body = models.TextField(default='No Description')
    pk_relation = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"For: {self.assigned_to.username} // id: {self.id}"
```

Signals.py:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Follow)
def create_notification(*args, **kwargs):
    follow = kwargs['instance']
    if kwargs['created']:
        # if task.created_by != task.assigned_to:
        if follow.follow_user != follow.user:
            Notification.objects.create(
                assigned_to = follow.user,
                group='NF',
                body=f"{follow.follow_user} followed you! ID: {follow.id}",
                pk_relation=follow.id
            )
    else:
        # if follow.created_by != task.assigned_to:
        if follow.follow_user != follow.user:
            if follow.follow_user != follow.old_instance.follow_user:
                Notification.objects.create(
                    assigned_to = follow.user,
                    group='NF',
                    body=f"{follow.follow_user} unfollowed you.",
                    pk_relation=follow.id
                )

@receiver(post_save, sender=Notification)
def send_notification_info(*args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            f"notification_group_{kwargs['instance'].assigned_to.id}", {
                'type':'notification_info'
            }
        )
```

Please help. Im not too good, i feel i have left something out

Comment: Did you add method in apps.py which imports signals?

Comment: Yes I did. `class NotificationConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'notifications'

    def ready(self):
        import notifications.signals`

Comment: How did you add `notification` app to `INSTALLED_APPS`? Just `notification` or `notificiation.apps.NotificationConfig`? Try the latest one if first one does not work.

Comment: Oh wow. I missed that. That was the problem. Thanks alot. I have been on this for days now. You are such a live saver. I pray for good things in your life. Very grateful

Comment: You're welcome, although I don't actually understand why it works only this way, not the other...

Comment: hi @vagifm , please allow me to distrub you a bit.. Is there a way to use multiple instances and senders (different models) in django signals. See the code below

Comment: @vagifm     
`@receiver(post_save, sender=Comment)
@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def create_comment_notification(*args, **kwargs):
    #comments  notifier
    comment = kwargs['instance']
    post = kwargs['instance']
    if kwargs['created']:
        if comment.author != comment.post_connected:
            Notification.objects.create(
                assigned_to = post.author,
                group='NC',
                body=f"{comment.author} commented: {comment.content} on your post.",
                pk_relation=comment.id
            ) `

Comment: @NelsonKehinde It is not possible using built in signal `post_save`, they are fired on *single* model's `save(...)` method. But you can define [your own signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/#defining-and-sending-signals). Hope this helps

Comment: OKay. THanks it is. Im grateful